# Is it possible to boot both an Intel mac and an Apple Silicon mac from the same system on an external drive?

Tags: mac, startup, apple-silicon, intel

I have a few macOS systems of various versions (latest Big Sur, Monterey, and now Ventura Beta) on an external drive I use for testing, and sometimes I need to test on an Intel mac and sometimes on an Apple Silicon mac: a 2019 16" MacBook Pro and a 2020 M1 Mac Mini. It'd be very convenient if I could boot these systems on either type of mac so that I only have to set each version of macOS up once, cutting my work in half.

Currently, though, I've installed the systems using an Intel mac, and if I try to boot my M1 Mac Mini from the same drive, then it doesn't even begin to start up. Is there any way to get this to work at all?

Comment: Which version of macOS are these few system using? What is the model/year of the Intel and Apple Silicon Macs? What version of macOS is installed on the internal drives of these Mac?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I've updated my question with these details

Comment: FYI: According to [this discussion](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/booting-an-m1-mac-with-a-big-sur-disk-taken-from-an-intel-mac.2273915/), the answer is no.